# How can I deploy a bookmarklet to users and restrict them from editing it?

Tags: javascript

I work for a large firm and have built a custom bookmarklet that certain users will soon be using for their work in IE11.

From a sys admin perspective, is there a way I can configure the bookmarklet's permissions so that they can run the bookmarklet but cannot edit properties of the file?

Note: the users all already have limited permissions in their Windows 10 PCs that prevent them from tampering with system files.

Comment: Favorites/bookmarks are all in the user context.  I don't think there is a an easy way to prevent people from changing it.  But you could deploy a bookmark with a group policy, in a way that any local changes would be destroyed when they logged in, or another group policy refresh event.

Comment: That would suffice! Thank you!